# MediaElement and RTSP

Tags: wpf, rtsp, mediaelement

Does MediaElement support RTSP?

I've got a stream going and I'm able to consume the stream with VLC Player via:

rtsp://192.168.1.17:554/stream

However, when trying to use Windows Media Player, I'm not able to stream it. Which begs the question, does MediaElement support RTSP?

I'm working with WPF on .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VLC has comprehensive support for `RTSP` (through live555 library), while support in Windows Media Player is limited.

You might want to check this article on MSDN: [Supported Media Formats, Protocols, and Log Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

> Supported Codecs
>
> Below is a rollup list of formats codecs supported by the
>   MediaElement. These encodings are supported regardless of the file
>   name extension.

See also: [MediaElement and custom RTSP stream](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/79a7ab95-7ea1-44d7-9ac1-4aa8cabfd712).