# RTSP and MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, rtsp, mediaelement

I'm having trouble trying to consume an RTSP feed with MediaElement:

I'm getting an exception:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D11BB

Which indicates that:

Windows Media Player cannot play the file because the specified protocol is not supported. If you typed a URL in the Open URL dialog box, try using a different transport protocol (for example, "http:" or "rtsp:").

What gives?

Comment: What URL are you trying to play (if public)? does it play in another media player? What type of file is it?

Comment: It plays on VLC Media Player but not for Windows Media Player

Comment: Media Player (and the mplayer controls) are all [ffdshow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffdshow)-based, whereas VLC has its own set of codecs. This is almost certainly a format not supported by ffdshow. You may get some joy by installing the [K-Lite codec pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm) which adds a lot of ffdshow codecs - but would require this isntallation on every machine using your app

Answer (score 1):

The error identifier is `NS_E_WMP_INVALID_PROTOCOL` and it happens because most likely this type of RTSP feed is not supported/compatible, see link on supported formats in your previous question [MediaElement and RTSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335456/mediaelement-and-rtsp)