# Play rtsp stream in WPF (or WinForms)

Tags: wpf, winforms, rtsp, mediaelement

Is there a way to play a rtsp:// stream in WPF (or alternatively WinForms)?

I have tried [`MediaElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) and [`MediaUriElement`](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) and none of them worked. I have also read a lot about WMP being able to play rtsp (which should translate to `MediaElement` too) but in reality WMP doesn't play it on a Windows 7 x64. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335456/mediaelement-and-rtsp) but I am hoping that is not a definite answer.

Has this anything to do with the video codec being used?

VLC plays the rtsp stream just fine.

I am looking for either a WPF or WinForms component or an alternative solution.

Comment: did you ever find an alternative that did not require VLC to be installed?

Comment: Actually, yes. VLC need not be installed. You can have your own copy of VLC (from ZIP) side-by-side with your app/components and reference that instead. I can't recall the details but I am sure I ended up using my own local copy of VLC (which was not registered as a system media player).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [VideoLan DotNet for WinForm, WPF & Silverlight 5](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) which seems to do the trick for now. The downside is that you need to have VLC installed. It is not a standalone thing.

I hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 9):

Try Accord.Net (http://accord-framework.net/). It has a very simple interface and is available as a nuget package (Accord.Video.FFMPEG). It can be used to retrieve a Bitmap instance which can be used in WinForms/WPF. The downside is that it doesn't support Mono (not sure what platform you're targeting).

Example:

```
VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();
reader.Open("rtsp://192.168......");

while (true)
{
   Bitmap frame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();
   //Do whatever with the frame...
}

reader.Close();
```

Comment: This is a terribly inefficient library for showing live video (at least in WPF) but it worked perfectly for the project I was working on.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never; take a look at this control:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/885869/Stream-Player-control

> It is a FFmpeg-based stream player control, which can do the following:
>
> 1. Play a RTSP/RTMP video stream
> 2. Retrieve the current frame being displayed by the control
>
> The control has no additional dependencies and a minimalistic interface.
>
> Requirements
>
> 1. The WinForms version of the control is implemented using .NET Framework 2.0
> 2. The WPF version of the control is implemented using .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
>
> Both versions are built using the x86 platform target.

Comment: Thank-you for summarising